# Flutter configureFlutterEngine method in Android Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, flutter

When exactly **configureFlutterEngine()** method is called in **Android** lifecycle? in **onCreate()**?

Answer (score 1):

According to official Flutter API docs found in [this](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterEngineConfigurator.html) link :

> This method is called after the given **FlutterEngine** has been
>   attached to the owning **FragmentActivity**.

The FlutterEngine is the container through which Dart code can be run in an Android application.

An explanation 'attached to the owning **FragmentActivity**' : Once an Activity is created, and its associated FlutterEngine is executing Dart code, the Activity should invoke this method. At that point the **FlutterEngine** is considered "attached" to the Activity and all ActivityAware plugins are given access to the Activity.